# Using Tessy with Subversion

Tags: c, unit-testing, svn, embedded

I have an embedded C project which uses subversion for source control. I want to use [Tessy](http://www.hitex.com/index.php?id=module-unit-test) for unit testing and have these tests archived in subversion too. However, it generates many small files which will make analysing diffs for the actual source code changes a real pain. Trying to actually look at the source changes when there are hundreds of Tessy related files changed will make it impossible.

Does anyone know if there is a setting to have these stored in a less problematic format or any suggestions for a viable solution? What would be ideal is if it could store everything as, for example, an xml file - this would make browsing directory diffs easier and would allow the actual content to be human readable as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to archive the unit-test results?  You should set your system up in such a way that you can exactly recreate the results for any point in time simply by checking out the appropriate revision and re-running the test suite.  (Note that I know nothing about Tessy...)

Comment: The unit test results I don't mind not having since this should be highly reproducible. However, the tests themselves should be archived with the source.

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood ;)  In that case, is it not possible to maintain all of your test infrastructure in a parallel directory hierarchy in your repository, rather than interleaved with your source directory hierarchy?

Comment: It is in a sub-directory, but it still creates hundreds of files, which show up in the diff.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question ...

> Does anyone know if there is a setting to have these stored in a less problematic format or any suggestions for a viable solution?

- The TESSY recommended way is to do utilize the database save feature found under in File menu (and in a variety of right-click menu's).  This creates a binary .tmb file which contains everything related to your tests.  By default the .tmb file is stored in the backup directory in your Tessy Project folder.  The config folder, backup folder and the PDBX file would then all be stored in SVN.  See the Tessy Users Manual (Backup, restore, version control chapter) for more specifics.

> What would be ideal is if it could store everything as, for example, an xml file - this would make browsing directory diffs easier and would allow the actual content to be human readable as well.

- That would be ideal, but unfortunately is not really an option.  Having everything stored as a binary file makes it impossible to do a useful diff.  The other problem with this method is that it disconnects a change to the test from the file that is checked into SVN - unless the tester specifically performs a database save.

Yes I realize xUnit testing frameworks don't have those limitations, but Tessy has some features (like MCDC and DO178B support) that the xUnit frameworks do not have baked in.

So how do you work in this environment. Key word - Discipline.

We set up internal procedures for who and how tests gets updated.  When the proecedures are followed we are able to deal with the limitations presented above.  It is not optimal, but with some internal discipline it can work.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into automating the backup/restore process with a script.. do you have any tips for how you handle the issues it brings? (Apart from discipline - do you keep the test data in the same repository as the source code? Because using binary files will make diff-ing and merging impossible, as you say..)

Comment: We do keep the .tmb files in the same repository.  As for tips ... We had a team of testers writing unit tests.  That team used a shared Excel spreadsheet during development to track the files that we had left to test as well as the files/tests currently being developed.  As we transition to more maintenance we are using a wiki.  When you start to update a test, enter the test name by your name in the wiki.  When you are done, you need to clear the name of the test so that others can do it.  It is not optimal, but with the limitations you are really left with following a defined process